# Doing Michael Spivak's Exercises

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, soft-question, big-list, book-recommendation

I am doing Spivak's Calculus, and I find it **EXTREMELY** difficult.

I usually ask questions here because I cannot do the problems on my own.

1. *How long should it take to do a Spivak problem?*
2. *Is it preparatory for contest problems such as Putnam?*

Thanks!

Comment: Putnam problems are way, way way way way way more difficult than Spivak. Can't put enough ways.

Comment: @MattSamuel, did you ever try Putnam? How did it go for you? But how long should it take me to do a Spivak problem?

Comment: I've added an answer. I've never really been able to solve the Putnam problems.

Comment: @MattSamuel, did you at least try perhaps?

Comment: Yeah. It didn't work out.

Comment: @MattSamuel, I suppose people who have won IMO's are really the ones who get Putnam... but still, I suppose it is better not to give up hope just yet..

Comment: Certainly no reason to give up hope, if you're in 11th grade you've got some time.

Comment: Luckily if you're interested in research and have terrible with Putnam problems you'll discover that research is not at all like driving Putnam problems.

Answer (score 3):

As far as advanced math goes, Spivak's problems are rather easy. I recommend you not let this discourage you though. Instead you should spend a very long time solving the problems until eventually you have brought yourself up to that level. This is the way to succeed in advanced math.

Comment: I suppose I *could* have an edge in the future. Being in 11th grade gives me time to practice to get to Putnam eventually.. Any person experience on Spivak you could offer? (+1)

Answer (score 3):

Spivak is best studied with an instructor, and not on your own.  When I taught from Spivak, I found that even the top students needed help and encouragement.

Learning to write proofs is preparatory for the Putnam, and Spivak may help with that.

Comment: @GE Did you ever take the Putnam?

Comment: Yes, I was a Putnam Fellow.

Comment: wow. Which year of University (freshman, sophomore...) how did you manage it? Will you tell me how you practiced for it?

Comment: @GE? I am actually very interested and await your response

Comment: Nowadays, many colleges and university math departments have coaching and practice leading up to the Putnam.  But U C Santa Barbara back in the 1970's didn't.  For those not yet in college, try http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/ for practice.

Comment: @GE, did you have practice from High School?